# Delphi dbexpress MySQL query format

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-2010, dbexpress

I am using `Delphi 2010 dbexpress` components to connect to my `MySQL` database. 
I am facing a problem executing this query.

```
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  SQLQuery1.SQL.Add('Select ForNo,Description from fortab');
  SQLQuery1.Open;
```

It gives me an error saying
**DBX Error :Unsupported field type**.
 now if I have the only 1 field in the query it will work fine i.e.

```
Select Description from fortab;
```

or

```
Select ForNo from fortab;  

fortab structure 
    ForNo: int(10) unsigned  NOT NULL, Primary key
    Description: varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Can anyone specify me the proper format of retrieving multiple fields from the table?
Or is it that I will have to write individual queries for each field?

Comment: Can you post the definition of your table? It's hard to say what your problem might be without it. What are the column names and data types?

Comment: @KenWhite have edited my question with table structure

Comment: Which version of MySQL and  LibMySQL.dll are you using?

Comment: What is `int(10)`? I don't use MySQL, but an `int` should be an `int`, and shouldn't need a width specifier. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: @KenWhite int(10) is supported in MySQL.

Comment: @RRUZ MySQL : 5.5 and LibMySQL.dll : 5.5.11.0.   
also facing problems with libmysql.dll getting errors for `libmysql.dll not fount in system path` any views how do i tackle it.

Comment: I use Mysql 5.1 with dbexpress without problems, maybe your issue is related to the Mysql version ,because according to the documentation dbexpress support Mysql 4.0, 5.0 and 5.1 versions (http://support.codegear.com/article/39758)

Comment: @Shirish11 - didn't know that; thanks. I learned something new. :)

Comment: @RRUZ can u tell me where do I have to place LibMySQl.dll?

Comment: @Shirish11, I use  a folder included in the `PATH` enviroment variable, something like `Windows\System32`, but remember I use mysql 5.1 not 5.5.

Comment: @RRUZ `Path` as in the `system path` or `user path` cause i still cant get it going with MySQL 5.0.21

Comment: I suggest using ADO and not DBX to connect to MySQL.

Comment: @Johan possibly that's the only option left with me :(

Comment: Try casting the fields as char  Select cast(ForNo as Char(10)) as CForNo, Description ...

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone specify me the proper format of retrieving multiple fields from the table?

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM atable
WHERE field1 > 100
ORDER BY field1
```

Comment: I know but its not working for me. I have tried the same query using `BDE and MyDAC` it works fine but when it comes to `dbExpress` it fails. Have also tried the same in `BDS 2006` but  no success.